# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Mysql InsertOrUpdate

Tags: mysql, node.js

[image]
When I entered this data using Mysql Stored Procedure, I got this error.
Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: please `console.log(req.body)`  and `console.log('emp id =',emp.id)`

Answer (score 0):

the problem exist in your front-end form,
you have set a `name` of your inputs inside your form

```
 in the front-end :
 <input type="text" name="id">

 in the back-end :
 const id = req.body.id
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is not from the mySQL neither is it from the stored-procedure created. It is due to the fact that, the

`req.body`   is undefined.

Possible solutions.

- Make sure you import *body-parser* package and use it to pass the json data. That is

`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Expecting your response.